# Save specific data from array

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to find a way that allows me to save specific data from a array (or JSONP output).

Lets say I have this,

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [
    {'title' : 'Star Wars', 'id' : '1'},
    {'title' : 'Inception', 'id' : '2'},
    {'title' : 'Inherent Vice', 'id' : '3'}
  ];
}
```

I display the results like this,

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{ movie.id }} : {{ movie.title }} - <a href="#">Add Movie to watchlist</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you click on `add movie to watchlist` I want to store that movie title and id in a scope so I can use it later. How could I do that?

Here is the plunkr example http://plnkr.co/edit/tycuNmJy71Yr4SUia2e5?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code::**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/e5Hm3SFz4oYNvmfGbQ2Z?p=preview)**

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
           {{ movie.id }} : {{ movie.title }} - <a href="#" ng-click="addMovie(movie)">Add Movie to watchlist</a>
       </div>      
  WishList: {{wishlist}}
   </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [
    {'title' : 'Star Wars', 'id' : '1'},
    {'title' : 'Inception', 'id' : '2'},
    {'title' : 'Inherent Vice', 'id' : '3'}
  ];
  $scope.wishlist = [];

  $scope.addMovie = function(movie)
  {
    $scope.wishlist.push({id: movie.id, title: movie.title});
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the `push` function was what I'm looking for. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I added the function to your plnkr

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hm9IImSDgJKkK6efpups?p=info)

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [
    {'title' : 'Star Wars', 'id' : '1'},
    {'title' : 'Inception', 'id' : '2'},
    {'title' : 'Inherent Vice', 'id' : '3'}
  ];
  
  $scope.select = function (movie) {
    //do your stuff here
    console.log(movie.title);
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    {{ movie.id }} : {{ movie.title }} - <a href="#" ng-click="select(movie)">Add Movie to watchlist</a>
  </div>
</div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write a function in which you can pass the id of the selected item and store it in a scope variable.
Like below :

```
  $scope.getDetails = function(id){
   alert(id);
   $scope.storedMovie = $scope.movies[id].title;
   alert($scope.storedMovie)
 }
```

[UPDATED PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/5eUANiFwaXG3FgGKtxqN?p=preview)